# ExtJs Ajax request exception synchronous

Tags: extjs

I have a web-application in ExtJs. I need to do logout, when response status of Ajax request is 401. I use this code:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function(connection, response, options){
        if (response){
            if (response.status == 401 && myApp.auth.userInfo != null){
                myApp.auth.logout();
            }
        }
    });
```

It works, but when I have a few requests myApp.auth.logout(); calls several times and I can't to login again, after reloading page I can login. Is there any filters for requests or some method to make Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception') synchronous, that function myApp.auth.logout(); calls only one time?

Comment: Did you try to set a [buffer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.EventManager-method-addListener) config on the listener so that it fires only once within the specified time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this. This makes sure the success and failure callbacks are not executed, your application should stop (perhaps the following requests hitting your override are due to the failure/callbacks being executed in cascade), then execute `logout`

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function(connection, response, options){
    if (response){
        if (response.status == 401 && myApp.auth.userInfo != null){
            delete options.failure;
            delete options.callback;
            myApp.auth.logout();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `single: true` so your handler will handle just the next firing of the event, and then remove itself.

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function (connection, response, options) {
    response && response.status == 401 && myApp.auth.userInfo != null && myApp.auth.logout();
}, null, {
    single: true
});
```

(See [documentation](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-on))

Comment: Your example didn't work, may be there is unnecessary parameter "null"?